# how to change the time zone to MST in sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, timezone, datetime-format

I have a query that fetches the time zone in MST format. But for few rows it is giving in PT.

The query I have used is -

```
SELECT   cca.last_update_date,
to_char(cast(cast(cca.last_update_date as timestamp with time zone) at time zone 'MST' as timestamp),'HH:MI:SS AM') mst_time
FROM     CMP_CWB_AUDIT CCA
```

Can anybody help me how to change the time format to MST in sql query ?

Comment: What is the data type of column `last_update_date`?

Comment: TIMESTAMP @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: What is the time zone of these values?

Comment: I dont know the current time zone in the table. It may vary but I want the output to have MST time zone

Comment: When the data type is `TIMESTAMP` (without time zone) and the actual time zone is not known by design then you cannot change time zone to MST. Oracle has no built-in crystal ball.

Comment: The time conversion is from pst to mst .....

Comment: But your last comment was "I don't know the current time zone" - Is the time zone of `last_update_date` values PST or is it unknown?

Comment: I think you are trying to belittle a person's effort than help them.... I will try to resolve this myself but Thanks for the help ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the time zone of `last_update_date` is given in `PST` you can simply run

```
SELECT cca.last_update_date,
   from_tz(cca.last_update_date, 'PST') at time zone 'MST' AS mst_time
FROM CMP_CWB_AUDIT CCA
```

When you run `cast(last_update_date as timestamp with time zone)` then Oracle is actually doing

```
from_tz(last_update_date, SESSIONTIMEZONE)
```

In case your current session time zone is `PST`, the result will be correct. However, as the `SESSIONTIMEZONE` could change at any time the result might be wrong.

Running `CAST(<TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE> AS TIMESTAMP)` is pointless when your output is `'HH:MI:SS AM'`, it does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

The `TIMESTAMP` data type does not have a time zone. But if you know that `last_update_date` is in MST, you can convert it to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` using the `FROM_TZ` function.

```
select from_tz( cca.last_update_date, 'MST' ) from CMP_CWB_AUDIT cca
```

If the column is in a different time zone from MST, you can convert it using the `AT TIME ZONE` clause:

```
select from_tz( cca.last_update_date, 'UTC' ) at time zone 'MST' from CMP_CWB_AUDIT cca
```

Comment: is there a way to know the timezone of the column?

Comment: "in a different time zone from MST" does not mean `UTC`. If time zone is not known then there is nothing you can convert.

Comment: The time conversion is from pst to mst  @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: Yes, i was just using UTC as an example. Obviously the time zone of the column needs to be knows, even if it is not part of the datatype. It's just common, I think, to store things in a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` field where the time zone is implicitly assumed to be the db time zone.